# Oracle 19c Regex - Repeating alphabets

Tags: regex, oracle, oracle19c

I'm working in Oracle 19c. I've a requirement to replace a word with a space if the word contains only the repeating alphabets.

```
Input - 'AAAA TEST CDDDD TEST'  Output - TEST CDDDD TEST
Input - 'BAD GHHHH TEST XXXX'   Output - BAD GHHHH TEST
```

These are some of the sample inputs and expected outputs. So far I've tried these options.

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('BAD AAAAA FOR ABBBB', '(\W|^)([A-Z]{3,50})(\W|$)', '') AS result
FROM dual;

SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('BAD AAAAA FOR ABBBB', '(\b)([A-Z]{3,50})(\b)', '') AS result
FROM dual;

SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('BAD AAAAA FOR ABBBB', '(\W|^)([A-Z]{3,50})(\W|$)','\1\3')
FROM dual
```

But none of these helped and (\b) is not supported in Oracle. Is there any solution?

Comment: Could you simply use `(?: |^)([A-Z])\1+(?: |$)` where instead of using boundaries you check if preceeding and follwoing your match must be a space or start/end of line? Replace with a single space. See at https://regex101.com/r/58a2qu/latest

Comment: Try the following, `(?:^| *)\b(.)\1{3,50}\b(?:$)?`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another simple method is to divide and `replace` as follows:

```
WITH INPUT_STRING AS (
    SELECT 'BAD AAAAA FOR ABBBB' STR FROM DUAL
)
SELECT LISTAGG(S_STR, ' ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY LVL) FROM
(SELECT
    STR, REGEXP_SUBSTR(STR, '[^ ]+', 1, LEVEL) S_STR, LEVEL LVL
  FROM
    INPUT_STRING
CONNECT BY
    LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT(STR, ' ') + 1) TT
    WHERE REPLACE(S_STR,SUBSTR(S_STR,1,1), NULL) IS NOT NULL;
```

[DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/jr4SZPd1)

If you have multiple string as mentioned by @Barbaros Özhan then you can use the following query:

```
WITH INPUT_STRING AS (
    SELECT 'BAD AAAAA FOR ABBBB' STR FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'BAD GHHHH TEST XXXX' STR FROM DUAL
)
SELECT LISTAGG(S_STR, ' ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY LVL) FROM
    (SELECT
        STR, REGEXP_SUBSTR(STR, '[^ ]+', 1, LVL) S_STR, LVL
      FROM
        INPUT_STRING 
        CROSS JOIN (SELECT LEVEL AS LVL FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 50)
        WHERE REGEXP_SUBSTR(STR, '[^ ]+', 1, LVL) IS NOT NULL
    ) TT
    WHERE REPLACE(S_STR,SUBSTR(S_STR,1,1), NULL) IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY STR;
```

[DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/5bM1_-I1)

Answer (score 1):

Oracle does not, natively, support matching word boundaries in regular expressions.

---

#### Option 1: Using Java Regular Expressions

If you have Java enabled in the database then you can compile a Java class:

```java
CREATE AND COMPILE JAVA SOURCE NAMED RegexParser AS
public class RegexpUtils {
  public static String replaceAll(
    final String value,
    final String regex,
    final String replacement
  ){
    if (value == null){ return null; }
    if (regex == null){ return value; }
    return value.replaceAll(regex, replacement == null?"":replacement);
  } 
}
/
```

And create a PL/SQL wrapper function:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION regexp_java_replace_all(
  value       IN VARCHAR2,
  regex       IN VARCHAR2,
  replacement IN VARCHAR2
) RETURN VARCHAR2
AS LANGUAGE JAVA NAME 'RegexpUtils.replaceAll( java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String ) return java.lang.String';
/
```

and then you can use word boundaries in the regular expression (or any other regular expression that Java supports):

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_JAVA_REPLACE_ALL(
         'BAD AAAAA FOR ABBBB',
         '\b([A-Z])\1{2,}\b',
         NULL
       ) AS result
FROM   dual;
```

Which outputs:

> | RESULT |
> | --- |
> | BAD FOR ABBBB |

---

#### Option 2: Recursively Look for Words in the String

```sql
WITH replacements (value, spos) AS (
  SELECT value, 1 FROM table_name
UNION ALL
  SELECT SUBSTR(value, 1, spos - 1)
         || CASE
            WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(
                   CASE epos
                   WHEN 0
                   THEN SUBSTR(value, spos)
                   ELSE SUBSTR(value, spos, epos - 1 - spos)
                   END,
                   '^([A-Z])\1{2,}$'
                 )
            THEN NULL
            ELSE CASE epos
                 WHEN 0
                 THEN SUBSTR(value, spos)
                 ELSE SUBSTR(value, spos, epos - 1 - spos)
                 END
            END
         || CASE
            WHEN epos > 0
            THEN SUBSTR(value, epos - 1)
            END,
         CASE
         WHEN epos = 0
         THEN 0
         WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(
                CASE epos
                WHEN 0
                THEN SUBSTR(value, spos)
                ELSE SUBSTR(value, spos, epos - 1 - spos)
                END,
                '^([A-Z])\1{2,}$'
              )
         THEN spos + 1
         ELSE epos
         END
  FROM   replacements r
         CROSS JOIN LATERAL(
           SELECT REGEXP_INSTR(value, '[^A-Z]', spos, 1, 1) AS epos
           FROM   DUAL
         )
  WHERE  spos > 0
)
  SEARCH DEPTH FIRST BY value SET order_id
  CYCLE value, spos SET is_cycle TO 1 DEFAULT 0
SELECT value
FROM   replacements
WHERE  spos = 0;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (value) AS 
SELECT 'BAD AAAAA FOR ABBBB' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'AAAA TEST CDDDD TEST' FROM DUAL
```

Outputs:

| VALUE |
| --- |
| TEST CDDDD TEST |
| BAD FOR ABBBB |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/oh-G6O3T)